# Is there a way to perform a mouseover (hover over an element) using Selenium and Python bindings?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-bindings

Reading [here](http://groups.google.com/group/selenium-developers/browse_thread/thread/eebb4269d53b4a01), there apparently used to be a `RenderedWebElement` class with a `hover` method. It, however, was exclusively made for Java (I have searched the Python bindings documentation to no avail) and has since been deprecated for Java.

A `hover` can't be performed using [`action_chains`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html) nor by using a [`WebElement`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html) object either.

Any ideas as to how to do this for Python? I have been [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232390/is-there-a-proved-mouseover-workaround-for-firefoxdriver-in-selenium2) but it uses `RenderedWebElement` and hence doesn't help too much.

*I am using: Python 2.7, Windows Vista, Selenium 2, Python Bindings*

**EDIT:** There is a method `mouse_over` for a `selenium.selenium.selenium` object but I cannot figure a way to create an instance without having the stand-alone server running already.

**EDIT** Please go through the comments of the reply marked as answer just in-case you have misconceptions like I did !

Answer (score 134, accepted):

To do a hover you need to use the `move_to_element` method.

Here is an example

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

firefox = webdriver.Firefox()
firefox.get('http://foo.bar')
element_to_hover_over = firefox.find_element_by_id("baz")

hover = ActionChains(firefox).move_to_element(element_to_hover_over)
hover.perform()
```

Comment: the last line should be "hover.perform()"
Yes I have tried that out but when I said hover I had this idea that when I hovered over an element it would show me the text which is supposed to be displayed (like if u hover over the "flag" element,just above this comment you get a "Flag this post for serious problems or moderator attention" popout (I dont know what to call it)) Any ideas?

Comment: that has nothing to do with hovering, the CSS being applied does but what you are after is the title of the element. For that you need to use `get_attribute('title')` on the WebElement

Comment: I thought that was the way to get it....was wrong I guess....thanks for giving the right way to go about it!

Comment: Any idea when this will be supported on mac?  I get the "Cannot perform native interaction" error

Comment: to add to my comment from almost a year ago, this appears to be addressed on Mac.  I'm using 2.26 python bindings and no longer get "cannot perform native interaction" error

Answer (score 8):

@AutomatedTester have given the community a great solution!

Below is how I used it.

I used signal to properly quit **PhantomJS** since it sometimes hangs in the current process.

I prefer to use *`find_element_by_xpath`* since xpath can be easily found in chrome.

Here's how:

> Right click -> Inspect -> Right click ->  Copy -> CopyXpath

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import signal

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.implicitly_wait(3)

def hover(browser, xpath):
    element_to_hover_over = browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
    hover = ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(element_to_hover_over)
    hover.perform()



browser.service.process.send_signal(signal.SIGTERM)  # kill the specific phantomjs child proc
browser.quit()
```