# Selenium Python right click "Open link in new Window" - (Windows 7)

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

Description of my web page:

When I enter some details on my web Page it shows up couple of different links.

Out of that links, I need to click on one link and continue my testing from there on.

The problem is the new link always opens in a new Tab instead of a new window. I have tried the following option but it still opens the new link a Tab only.

Method 1 tried:

```
 link =  driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("MyLink")
 action = ActionChains(driver)
 action.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).click(link).key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
```

Comment: Please show the HTML code of the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either:

a) set a wait time or

b) hover over the element and then click.

See:
[Is there a way to perform a mouseover (hover over an element) using Selenium and Python bindings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252558/is-there-a-way-to-perform-a-mouseover-hover-over-an-element-using-selenium-and)

Comment: I have tried the option mentioned in the link you gave me . It is not working either. Any other suggestions? When I run my scripts it is still opening the new link in a new tab. I want that link to be opened in a new window instead.

Comment: You should post your HTML if you want more help, it's difficult to tell what's going on without that.

Comment: Thanks Bobby. I used this following code and I was able to perform "Right click - Open Link in new Window" and Switch to New Window. link =  driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("My LinK")
          action = ActionChains(driver)
          action.key_down(Keys.SHIFT).click(link).key_up(Keys.SHIFT).perform()
          time.sleep(15)
          self.driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[-1])
          title = self.driver.title