# If random number hover element

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to create a job that creates a random number generator and if it is above 3, it will hover an element on a website.

Two problems.

```
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.css_selector, '.origin-telemetry-shell-submenu-current-area'))).click()
```

This line does not seem to work.  I want to click through all these elements
It gives me:

```
   if ( ww > 3 ):
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

And in relation to the CSS selector line

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/Bain3/PycharmProjects/untitled4/ha1.py", line 53, in <module>
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.css_selector, '.origin-telemetry-shell-submenu-current-area'))).click()

AttributeError: type object 'By' has no attribute 'css_selector'
```

The Css selector tends to work in Chrome and in Css Gadget.

I have attached an image and my code in textupload.

http://textuploader.com/d6hqs

https://ibb.co/b3v1U5

Comment: *if ( ww > 3)* : what does `ww` stands for?

Comment: ww should be the random number.  If it is above 3, then it goes on to hover the element randomly

Comment: Show how you defined `ww`. It doesn't seem to be number. Also do you mean `EC.element_to_be_clickable(('css_selector', '.origin-telemetry-shell-submenu-current-area'))).click()`?

Comment: @Andersson I believe so as .hover() is not correct apparently

Comment: definitely :) WebElement has no such attribute as `hover()` . I think you might need [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252558/is-there-a-way-to-perform-a-mouseover-hover-over-an-element-using-selenium-and)

Comment: @Andersson Thanks.  I am still getting     EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.css_selector, '.origin-telemetry-shell-submenu-current-area'))).click()
AttributeError: type object 'By' has no attribute 'css_selector' for line 53.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153253/discussion-between-andersson-and-hayden-darcy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (ww > 3)` seem to be redundant condition. If you don't want to handle numbers that are less than `3`, then just try to replace

```
# Get list of integers [1, 2, ... n]
indexes = [index for index in range(len(options))]
```

with

```
# Get list of integers [3, 4, ... n]
indexes = [index for index in range(3, len(options))]
```

this should allow you to get list of integers starting from `3`

Also, as was already mentioned, `By` has no such attribute as `css_selector`.

Note that variable names are case sensitive in `Python`. So you can use `By.CSS_SELECTOR` or `"css_selector"` instead

Answer (score 2):

You assign to `ww` the returned value from `print()`, which doesn't return anything so `ww` became `None`. Use `ww = randint(0, 9)`.

`By.css_selector` should be `By.CSS_SELECTOR`, all capital.

Comment: Thanks.  I am still having trouble with  EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.origin-telemetry-shell-submenu-current-area'))).click() as it seems to ignore the other CSS

Comment: @HaydenDarcy What do you mean by *ignore the other CSS*?

Answer (score 0):

Given this documentation https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index_exports_By.html, 
class `By` does not contain any css_selector field or property, that is why its raising *No Attribute Error*, maybe what you are looking for is `By.css(your_selector)`.

Hope it helps.