# Selenium class name changes based on hover movement

Tags: python, selenium

Javascript inside html changes to class name based on hover. Because of that I can not click on the object.

Please check [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnOGF.jpg) to see my html code and object image

what I try so far:

```
select_project = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH ,"//a[@class='smalltextnolink']")))
select_project.click()
```

and

```
select_project = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]")
select_project.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting by CSS partial match.

```
select_project = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[class^="smalltext"]')))
select_project.click()
```

Comment: didn't work got `TimeoutException` than I raised time from 2 to 10 but still same error

Answer (score 0):

Try using following CSS selector:

```
[onmouseover*='smalltextul']
```

Answer (score 0):

How about adding  tag into the xpath:

```
select_project = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a")
```

select_project.click()

Another option I think about is considering them as 2 different elements if you really want to locate them by class:

Keep the button hovered: [Is there a way to perform a mouseover (hover over an element) using Selenium and Python bindings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252558/is-there-a-way-to-perform-a-mouseover-hover-over-an-element-using-selenium-and)

```
firefox = webdriver.Firefox()
firefox.get('http://foo.bar')
element_to_hover_over = firefox.find_element_by_id("baz")
hover = ActionChains(firefox).move_to_element(element_to_hover_over)
hover.perform()
```

Then find the element with new class and perform the click