# Selecting button without ID in selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm learning with Python Selenium and I'm trying to click a button which doesn't seem to have an id. I get an error that the element could not be scrolled into view.

Could anyone help with how I click the element?

It might be useful to know that the button only appears when you mouse over a section of the page

HTML is:

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                    <button type="button" class="grey-bg btn btn-default btn-expand" title="Expand"></button>
                    <button type="button" class="grey-bg btn btn-default btn-export" title="Export"></button>
                    <button type="button" class="grey-bg btn btn-default btn-clone" title="Clone"></button>
                    <button type="button" class="grey-bg btn btn-default btn-stamp" title="Pin"></button>
                    <button type="button" class="grey-bg btn btn-default btn-delete" title="Delete"></button>
                </div>
```

I've tried to select by xpath:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title="Export"]').click()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't ```find_element_by_xpath``` work? Plus, it would be helpful if u provide the url of the website.

Comment: find_element_by_xpath doesn't seem to work unfortunately, unless I'm somehow pointing to the wrong element.

The page is behind a log in so I can't share it unfortunately

Comment: `//div/button[@title='Export']` try this xpath. `*` will consider all elements with `title=Export` attribute. additionally you can check for if element is inside iframe or not? if it is switch to frame then act on element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned, it appears when you mouse hover. Kindly refer to this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252558/is-there-a-way-to-perform-a-mouseover-hover-over-an-element-using-selenium-and) for mouse hover. And try to look for the button after then click using javascript as this doesn't need to be displayed in order to click.

`exportBtn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title="Export"]') driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", exportBtn)`

Answer (score 0):

From the error, it looks like the element hasn't been scrolled into view. In order to scroll to the element, just add this line to ur code:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title="Export"]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
element.click()
```

Hope that this helps!