# Parsing a link that becomes active only after pointing selenium python at it

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm doing a parser for Facebook, I need to get a link to a review on the page, but until you hover over the date `href='#'` and after hovering `href='https://www.facebook.com/tammy.hulcy/posts/4173758649374693`
I don't know what to do with these at all, I write code using selenium + bs
bs in order for me to parse the html code that I get using selenium

I also noticed that after hovering in the html code, the aria-descripedby tag appears. Maybe it's him

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1u3fs.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROswV.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hover over an element. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/8261754/16442723

After hovering, you can the use `get_attribute` method of the element to get the href value.