# Selecting an option in a CSS-based menu with WebDriver

Tags: java, drop-down-menu, selenium, hover, webdriver

I have a simple [CSS-based dropdown menu](https://www.servage.net/blog/2009/03/20/create-a-cool-css-based-drop-down-menu/), and I'm trying to click on one of the menu items in a Java Selenium (WebDriver) test.

[image]

Both the menu (`<ul>` element) and the items (`<a>`) have IDs and creating corresponding `WebElement` objects works fine. I'm trying to click on one of the items with code like:

```
   hoverOver(transfersMenu);
   transferLink.click();
```

In `hoverOver()`, **I've tried [all three answers from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6232390/56285), but none of them work**. I keep getting:

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: 
    Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with 
Command duration or timeout: 2.06 seconds
```

(I've tried calling `transferLink.click()` also *before* `hoverOver()`, in the hope that the implicit wait would make it work, but nope.)

**Any idea how to make the hovering work so that the link can be clicked?**

Selenium version 2.21.0. I'm running the tests on Linux (Ubuntu), using Firefox 13.0. A colleague just  tried on Windows (using Firefox 12.0), and it didn't work for him either.

**Update**: As per Slanec's tip in comments, and [these instructions](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AdvancedUserInteractions#Native_events_versus_synthetic_events), I tried `setEnableNativeEvents(true)` on the `FirefoxProfile`. At first this failed:

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: 
    Cannot perform native interaction: Could not load native events component.
```

...but after I **upgraded to Selenium 2.23.1**, I no longer get that complaint.

Still, the hovering doesn't work (with native events on or off). :-/

Comment: The accepted solution from the linked question should work =/. What do you actually see when running the test? Does the `hoverOver()` open the list visually, or not?

Comment: Some users in different questions about related things also suggest toggling the native events on/off.

Comment: @Slanec: it doesn't open the menu visually. (The only way I ever got the test passing was to *manually* hover over the menu with mouse, which allowed Selenium to click on the menu item.) Hmm, I'll look into native events...

Comment: @Slanec: did't get it working with native events either... see updated question.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code to hover over our menus for 1 second, before clicking a link, just like the one you are using:

```
action = new SeleniumActionHelper(driver);

WebElement currentUser = findElementByLinkText("testing1");
action.mouseHover(currentUser);
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

Of note, the mouse cursor needs to remain in the browser window for the hover to keep.  If the mouse cursor is outside of the browser window, I experience a quick flash of the menu, but it does not stay visible

Comment: It should be mentioned that `SeleniumActionHelper` appears to be from a project called [PrimeFaces](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/examples/trunk/showcase/src/test/java/com/prime/showcase/integration/SeleniumActionHelper.java?r=6585) and what `mouseHover()` does is essentially [same as this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6233282/56285).

Comment: So the only difference compared to what I've already tried is `Thread.sleep(1000)` - I tried it but still doesn't work for me. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try this exampale:

```
WebElement menuHoverLink= driver.findElement(By.id("test"));
actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLink).perform();
driver.findElement(By.id("test")).click();
Thread.sleep(6000);
```

Comment: I'm no longer working on that product (or in that company), so I can't (easily) try your solution. Perhaps this helps others though.

Answer (score 0):

How do you run your test classes? I found out that running WebDriver through ANT makes hover actions impossible, whereas running the test classes from command line (TestNG JAR) or from Eclipse works just fine.